# How to make a 2nd check after first row of validations

Tags: php

I have am trying to re-create a form register validation that I seen a few weeks ago but unable to figure it out.

I want to perform one last check after the first 3 checks then display the message

**validation code**

```
public function validateSignup(): bool
{
    $this->errors = [];

    if (empty($this->name) || (strlen($this->name) < 4))  {
        $this->errors['name'] = "Username must be at least 4 characters.";
    }
    if (empty($this->email) || (filter_var($this->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)) {
        $this->errors['email'] = "Email address is required.";
    }
    if (empty($this->password) || strlen($this->password) < 6) {
        $this->errors['password'] = "Password is required.";
    }

    return empty($this->errors);
}
```

This works great for the validation requirements but I want to add another step, to check if email or username is taken, I know how to do this traditionally but wanted to make it different without giving information away.

I have a Helper to tell me if an email is in the database called **alreadyExists**

what I am trying to accomplish is a 2nd check after that

**Example**

```
public function validateSignup(): bool
{
    $this->errors = [];

    if (empty($this->name) || (strlen($this->name) < 4))  {
        $this->errors['name'] = "Username must be at least 4 characters.";
    }
    if (empty($this->email) || (filter_var($this->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)) {
        $this->errors['email'] = "Email address is required.";
    }
    if (empty($this->password) || strlen($this->password) < 6) {
        $this->errors['password'] = "Password is required.";
    }

    return empty($this->errors);


    ## after it checks validation with no errors check if already exists 


    if ($this->name) Helpers::alreadyExists("user", "name", $this->name) {
        $this->errors['name'] = "Unable to register user with provided data.";
    }

    return $this->errors;

}
```

Comment: It will never reach your second check since you leave the function with the first return. Wrap the first return inside a if function checking if there is an error and it works. Or remove the first return completely. But then you tell the user if the username is already used even when he leaves the form empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function validateSignup(): bool { 
$this->errors = [];

if (empty($this->name) || (strlen($this->name) < 4))  {
    $this->errors['name'] = "Username must be at least 4 characters.";
}
if (empty($this->email) || (filter_var($this->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)) {
    $this->errors['email'] = "Email address is required.";
}
if (empty($this->password) || strlen($this->password) < 6) {
    $this->errors['password'] = "Password is required.";
}

If(count($this->errors) > 0) {
return empty($this->errors);
}

## after it checks validation with no errors check if already exists 


if ($this->name) Helpers::alreadyExists("user", "name", $this->name) {
    $this->errors['name'] = "Unable to register user with provided data.";
}

return empty($this->errors);
}
```